I am not able to get a stable orbit in this three js and cannon js simulation
I am trying to create an app which simulates celestial bodies in space.
I am using three.js for rendering and cannon.js for physics simulation. Here with this code I am not able to get a stable orbit no matter how I tweak the parameters, the planet is just eventually crashing into the central body.
const G = 1;

objectsRef.current.forEach((obj, i) => {
  if (obj.body) {
    objectsRef.current.forEach((otherObj, j) => {
      if (i !== j && otherObj.body) {
        const distanceVector = new THREE.Vector3().subVectors(
          new THREE.Vector3(
            otherObj.body.position.x,
            otherObj.body.position.y,
            otherObj.body.position.z
          ),
          new THREE.Vector3(
            obj.body.position.x,
            obj.body.position.y,
            obj.body.position.z
          )
        );
        const distance = distanceVector.length();

        if (distance > 0) {
          // Calculate the gravitational force magnitude
          const forceMagnitude = (G * obj.body.mass * otherObj.body.mass) / (distance * distance);
          const force = distanceVector.normalize().multiplyScalar(forceMagnitude);

          // Apply the force to the object
          obj.body.applyForce(new CANNON.Vec3(force.x, force.y, force.z), obj.body.position);

        }
      }
    }
  );

  // Update mesh position and quaternion based on body position and rotation
  obj.mesh.position.copy(obj.body.position);
  obj.mesh.quaternion.copy(obj.body.quaternion);
}

timestep is set to 1/60.
Am I doing something wrong?
I tried simulation using these parameters,
G = 1;

for central body:
Mass = 1000
position = (0,0,0)
Initial velocity = (0,0,0) (stationary)

for the planet:
Mass = 1
position = (20, 0, 0)
Initial velocity = (0, 7, 0)

timestep = 1/60;

It should give planet a stable orbit around the central body but the planet is eventually crashing into the central body after a few elliptical orbits.

It would be beneficial to make a runnable Stack Snippet ™️
